# Alternate download for minecraft recources?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ever since minecraft stopped using the amazon site to host it's resource files, I've been unable to run 1.6+ minecraft. I'm sure this is because I can't get the native resources on startup. For instance:

> couldn't download http://resources.download.minecraft.net/cf/cf23204a9cca2ac7f9674168cc063cfb4dbe001f for job 'Resources'java.lang.RuntimeException: Hash did not match downloaded file (Expected cf23204a9cca2ac7f9674168cc063cfb4dbe001f, downloaded 9216ea5b710f7b6c49873ffb221c7ad848d5c9d5)

It gives this error about 50 times, then finally:

> Java.lang.NullPointerException: Initializing game Client>  at azd.a(SourceFile:502}Client>     at azd.Z(SourceFile:340) Client>    at azd.e(SourceFile:689) Client>    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:103)

The game crashes.

This gives me the same errors on 1.5.2 and prior however it doesn't crash and seems to run perfectly.

Until today it would work in play offline mode as well.

This computer is in an environment with internet restrictions. The old amazon site wasn't blocked, so it was no problem to download the required items each time.

All I need is an alternate download for the files i need to run 1.7.2, or maybe if I can be told how to get to them from a computer that can run 1.7.2. Also how to run them without having to re-re-download them.

Comment: What's wrong with being able to update the game from the official site?

Comment: The official site is blocked in this environment.

Comment: ...what are you trying to do?  Play MC at work or school or something?

Comment: No, I'm actually at home. Why?

Comment: If you're at home, how is it blocked?  From what I can tell of that error message, it's more a problem with a bad download, not a blocked site.

Comment: 1. Did you update to the new launcher?
2. Have you tried doing a full redownload of the game? (Delete %appdata%/.minecraft and the launcher, then download again)
If you didn't do (1), do it. If you didn't do (2), backup your .minecraft and delete the copy on %appdata%, then download the game again.

Comment: I live right next to a workplace and they allow me to use their wifi for my personal internet as well which unfortunately has restrictions with minecraft.net being one of them.

Comment: I have minecraft launcher 1.3.5, is that the new one? I've also tried a full redownload of the game, yes.

Comment: So the proper answer then is to either get them to unblock Minecraft, or buy your own internet.

Comment: So then there is no way to do this without doing one of those two things? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: With free wifi comes limitations.  If you don't like them, you can always get your own.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 6):

There are no official alternate download servers for Minecraft.

Comment: Could there be an unofficial one? Or are these files changed frequently to make this not possible?

Comment: It is against Mojang's TOS to distribute the minecraft.jar anywhere except for their official servers.

Comment: Are these viles the .jar? i figured they were just .dll or something.

Comment: Minecraft is coded in Java so there are no .dll files, just .jar files and the entire game is in this jar.

Comment: Could I download them at another location which isn't blocked and bring them to this computer? The 1.7.2.jar and .json files are already installed.

Comment: Yes you can do that. You just need to have access to the appdata folder on either computer.

Comment: Thank-you. Now I just need to know what they are specifically and how to use them where it won't redownload each time (because from what I see, from the dev console in the launcher, it downloads a -natives folder each time the game opens, and deletes it right after).